How to utilize zener diode specs
I'm learning about zener diodes and am unclear about how to interpret their dynamic resistance.  According to The Art of Electronics (Horowitz and Hill, first edition, p. 11-12):

Included in the specifications of a zener will be its dynamic resistance, given at a certain current.  (Useful fact: the dynamic resistance of a zener diode varies roughly in inverse proportion to current.)  For example, a zener diode might have a dynamic resistance of 10 ohms at 10mA, at its zener voltage of 5 volts.   Using the definition of dynamic resistance, we find that a 10% change in applied current will therefore result in a change in voltage of $$ \Delta V = R_{dyn}\Delta I = 10 \times 0.1 \times 0.01 = 10mV $$

So, my 5.1v zener would only give 5.05 volts? I'm not sure I'm understanding this correctly.  Does it mean that if a circuit were to provide a different current (let's say either 5mA or 15mA for instance), I could expect the zener voltage to be
$$ \Delta V = R_{dyn}\Delta I = 10 \times 0.005 = 50mV $$
So at 5mA I'd get 5.05 v
$$ \Delta V = R_{dyn}\Delta I = 10 \times 0.015 = 150mV $$
And at 15mA I'd get 4.95 volts?
Perhaps put a different way, if a datasheet gives as dynamic resistance at a certain current, how do I compute the dynamic resistance at a different current level?

You went wrong in two ways:

You used the same dynamic resistance \$r\$ for both \$I=5mA\$ and \$I=15mA\$

You confused average DC current with change in current \$\Delta I\$


Your calculations suggest that at a higher quiescent DC current you would end up with lower voltage across the diode, a claim which can be immediately refuted with a simulation. I'll measure the voltage across zener diode D1 while increasing the current through it from 1mA to 20mA:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The blue line is diode voltage, along which there is no point where slope (gradient) is negative, and where diode voltage falls as a result of a rise in current through it.
The slope of that blue plot at the point where current is \$I=5mA\$ is the tangent to the line at that point, shown in green. The red line shows the slope when current is \$I=15mA\$.
If you "move" along the red line from \$I=15mA\$ all the way to the left until \$I=5mA\$, you quickly leave the blue line, ending up well above it. The same problem occurs when you travel to the right along the green line from \$I=5mA\$; by the time you get to \$I=15mA\$, you are way off.
Those tangent lines are valid only so far left or right from the point of contact. They represent the change in voltage that would occur for very small changes in current. Dynamic resistance is the ratio of change in voltage to change in current \$r=\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I}\$ but only for very small \$\Delta I\$, so small that you don't leave the blue \$V\$ line by any appreciable distance. As the distance \$\Delta I\$ you travel left or right increases, the further away you get from the true \$V\$.
Also, you used the same \$r=10\Omega\$ for both conditions, \$I=5mA\$ and \$I=15mA\$, which isn't correct. Slope, representing dynamic resistance \$r\$, is very different at those two points.
It's hard to measure on those tangent lines what the actual \$r\$ is at those two points, but I'll give it a go. For \$I=5mA\$ (green):
$$ r_1 = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I} = \frac{5.000V-4.920V}{13.5mA - 0.5mA} = 6.2\Omega $$
When \$I=15mA\$ (red):
$$ r_2 = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I} = \frac{4.980V-4.950V}{13.0mA - 2mA} = 2.7\Omega $$
To check the artists' claims that dynamic resistance is approximately inversely proportional to the ratio of DC current:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{5mA}{15mA} &= \frac{1}{3} \\ \\
\frac{r_1}{r_2} &= \frac{6.2\Omega}{2.7\Omega} \\ \\
&= 2.3
\end{aligned}
$$
Not quite a factor of 3, but close enough. We can get a much better measure of dynamic resistance by pushing DC current trough the diode, then making tiny changes to that current and measuring the resulting change in voltage. I do this here by using two parallel current sources (which by KCL will sum), one to establish DC, and the other oscillating with 1μA peak-to-peak. In this scenario, a change of ±0.5μA is considered small enough:

simulate this circuit
This is the voltage at node A, which is the voltage across the diode with 5mA ± 0.5μA of current:

According to the legend bottom left, the green markers are separated by 6.1μV:
$$ r_1 = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I} = \frac{6.1\mu V}{1\mu A} = 6.1\Omega $$
The voltage at node B, where the diode is biased with 15mA DC:

$$ r_2 = \frac{\Delta V}{\Delta I} = \frac{2.7\mu V}{1\mu A} = 2.7\Omega $$
I'm surprised at this point that my rough approximations above were so close, considering I drew the tangent lines by eye in Inkscape.

You can't, in general. You can make approximations, but you can't calculate it precisely.
Two generalizations that can help: As mentioned in the excerpt, higher currents result in lower dynamic resistance. And also, higher-voltage zeners  have lower dynamic resistance than lower-voltage ones--this is particularly extreme below about 5~7 volts, where zener breakdown (rather than avalanche breakdown) dominates.
You can also check for I/V graphs, which most manufacturers will provide in the datasheet, at least for a selected sample of the zener voltages offered. (I've found that Nexperia is particularly good at providing these down to even very low currents.) The slope of the graph is the inverse of the dynamic resistance at that current (although note that they're usually on a log scale, so you'll need to convert). These are typical values, not guaranteed, but it's rare that there's a guaranteed min/max dynamic resistance to begin with.

Should I interpret the datasheet as "use this at the reported test current and expect good results?" And keep in mind that I'll know which way the dynamic resistance will change if a different current is applied but that I won't be able to predict the actual result?

@nuggethead Generally, the dynamic resistance is low enough that anything vaguely in the vicinity of the test current is more than accurate enough (considering, for instance, that the temperature coefficient will lead to much bigger differences in voltage than the change in current), especially if it's greater than the test current. If you need a very precise reference, you use something like a REF3433 or an LTZ1000, not just a regular zener diode.

Here is simulated the behavior of a Zener labelled 1N4735 (6.2 V @41 mA).
See how vary the Zener voltage (black curve) from ~ 6 V @ 1 mA to ~ 6.2 V @ 50 mA.
You can see that the "dynamic" resistance (red curve) is varying with the current ...
(from ~ 27 Ohm @ 1 mA to ~ 3 Ohm @ 50 mA).
Blue curve for Diode "power in".


You are mixing the DC bias point with dynamic resistance.
As an example, a Vishay 6.2V zener has nominally 6.2V over it at 41mA current through it. With a voltage tolerance of 5%. At that DC bias point, it rated with 2 ohms dynamic resistance at 1 kHz frequency.
It means that if you vary the 41mA current by e.g. +/- 1 mA sine wave, the zener voltage will vary by +/- 2 mV sine wave due to the dynamic resistance.
However, if you instead put 1mA DC bias through the zener, the voltage will of course not be 6.2V but less. And the dynamic resistance will be higher, rated at 700 ohms. Meaning, varying the 1mA by +/- 0.1 mA, the voltage over zener diode will vary by +/- 70 millivolts from the voltage it has at 1mA.
